# Корректное выполнение системного вызова QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

В таком виде системные вызовы Windows происходят корректно:

```
QProcess proc;
proc.start("taskkill", QStringList() << "/im" << clsprocs[i].c_str() << "/t" << "/f");
```

Однако вызовы с пайпом или перенаправлением потоков (`|` или `>`) никак не хотят работать. Пробовал и так, и сяк: `proc.start("tasklist > data.tmp")`, `proc.start("tasklist", QStringList() << ">" << "data.tmp")` и `proc.start("tasklist", QStringList() << "> data.tmp")`.

Как всё-таки заставить QProcess отработать корректный системный вызов?

Comment: Интерпретацией операторов перенаправления ввода-вывода занимается командный интерпретатор (powershell или bash например), исполняющий команду. А если уж запускаете процесс самостоятельно, то и перенаправлять следует самому.

Answer (score 0):

По подсказке @user7860670 проблема решилась.

Было так: `proc.start("tasklist", QStringList() << ">" << "data.tmp");`
Сделал так: `proc.start("cmd.exe", QStringList() << "/c" << "tasklist" << ">" << "data.tmp");`

То есть по факту, запустил интерпретатор и передал ему нужную мне команду (`cmd.exe /c ...`).